# How can I get the values of my variables from Javascript using Django?

Tags: javascript

I have this code using javascript :

```js
var arr = [
  'one',
  'two',
  'three',
  'four',
  'five'
];


for (var property1 in arr) {
  console.log(property1);
}
```

And when I execute this code I get :

```
'1'
'2'
'3'
'4'
```

But I would like to have this :

```
'one',
'two',
'three',
'four',
'five'
```

How can I do this using a loop for ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: use `for..of` like so: `for(var property1 of arr) {` - [it's bettter not to use `for..in` on arrays!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329476/5648954)

Comment: Thank you it is strange because in Python I will get the same result with a for..in !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) like following

```js
var arr = [
'one',
'two',
'three',
'four',
'five'
];


for(var property1 of arr) {
  console.log(property1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you it is strange because in Python I will get the same result with a for..in !

Comment: @JackPeter - Glad to help you mate!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!

If you want to loop through the array then you will need to use something besides `for..in`. You can use `for..of` or a `for` loop but it might be good to understand why this is happening.

`for..in` loops through the key/value pairs of an object. The variable in the parens gets set to the `key` of that key/value pair. In the case of the array, It will get set to the index or any enumerable property on the array. Thats why it prints numbers instead of words.

I'd also like to point out some iteration methods that might be useful outside of imperative loops.

`arr.forEach` will allow you to loop through an array without needing the extra `for` syntax.

```js
arr.forEach(item => console.log(item))
```

Other methods like `arr.map` and `arr.filter` will give you even more power as you begin to iterate through your list more.

```js
const numbers = [1,22,11,18,16];
const add = a => b => a + b;
const isEven = number => number %2 === 0;

const biggerEvenNumbers = numbers
  .map(add(1))
  .filter(isEven) // [2,12]
```